# Microsoft SQL variant type error pops up when I run hibernate 5

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Whenever I run my hibernate 5, I see this error:

```
ERROR: Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The "variant" data type is not supported.
```

I've never heard of a "variant" data type before. Or is it a category of data types? Not sure.

I checked the data types in all my tables, and these are the ones that are there: bigint, bit, date, datetime, int, numeric, varbinary, and varchar.

Where could this error be coming from? Is there somewhere else I should check for variant types?

**EDIT:**

I ran this query `select distinct data_type from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get all the data types in my database, and sql variant didn't show up. That's how I'm sure there isn't one.

Is there somewhere else this could be referenced?

EDIT 2:

A little bit more information on this. The application is a maven project. I created a normal java project and ran the same codes against the same database, and I didn't get any error about sql variant types.

So this issue seems to be tied to the hibernate dependency. I don't get it, really. This is the dependency I'm using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure those are your only datatypes. Your error very strongly suggests there's something with the datatype [`sql_variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017); which as the error (and a quick Google) suggests, isn't supported by JDBC.

Comment: @Larnu I ran this query: select distinct data_type from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. It showed me the data types in my database. There's no sql variant there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright. So, I checked the library I was using in my normal java application, and it's Hibernate 5.3.7. The one I'm using in my maven application is 5.4.0.

So I changed the hibernate library in my maven app to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

And now everything works. No complaints about some weird some weird Sql Variant type.

This issue also affects Hibernate search 5.11.0. You should use 5.10.5.Final.

Unfortunately, I don't have the proper credentials to raise this with the hibernate team on their issues tracker. Hopefully one of them will come across this post and address it. I know they're working on a hibernate search 6 and hibernate ORM 6, so that's good news!

Comment: I was facing with the same problem. 5.3.7 version worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is a bug in the MSSQL JDBC-Driver, see

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/pull/442

As mentioned in the [changelog](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md), this is fixed for versions >=6.3.2

> Fixed sql_variant issue with String type #442

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out

Comment: Not fixed in mssql-jdbc version 7.0.0.jre8.

Comment: I can confirm that version 7.2.2 fixes it for these newer versions of hibernate

Answer (score 2):

My application is a *spring-boot* `2.2.7` with *spring-data* which has a dependency with *hibernate-core* `5.4.15.Final`.
I was using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I tried upgrading `mssql-jdbc` to `8.3.1.jre8-preview` but this error persisted.

After downgrading hibernate-core to `5.3.7` it fixed my problem.

Thanks for the tip @Akin_Glen

Answer (score 1):

In my project
MSSQL version 2017.
springboot-parent version is 2.5.6.
hibernate-core version is 5.4.32.Final.
MSSQL Driver sqljdbc4 version 4.1
I get error when start project.
I see there's an answer said change driver version ,then i try mssql-jdbc version 6.2.2.jre8,it's dosen't work.
But version 9.4.1.jre8 it's worked solved the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hkfv.png)