# The variant data type is not supoprted

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to run a spring boot demo application here and I'm using JPA for my database connection. Upon running the demo service, I get the `SQLServerException: The "variant" data type is not supported.` error.

After a couple of searching, I found out that this is a bug based from the numerous results provided by google. However, I can't find how to fix it. I tried two different versions of `sqljdbc`, namely `4-2.0` and `6.0`. I also tried changing the data types from `VARCHAR(50)` to `NVARCHAR(128)` in the design mode of the `SQL Server Management Studio` but that didn't help as well. Please, any help will be much appreciated.

Here's my `pom.xml` just in case it could help solving this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.pluralsight</groupId>
    <artifactId>conference-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>conference-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Adding `application.properties` content as requested

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=conference-demo
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=13thSkull
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Comment: `application.properties` content.

Comment: @dm_tr, just added the `applicatoin.properties`

Comment: I suggest you check here too. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54203225

Comment: Don't use 6.0, use a newer version where the bug has been fixed, like the [duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56073478/5221149) says. See [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc) for list of available versions.

Comment: I see. So simply need to upgrade the version. Thanks for the help